# Bootstrap tooltip not styling correctly with Laravel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a couple tooltips to my navbar using Twitter Bootstrap and Laravel 4. However, it seems the Bootstrap CSS is not styling the tooltip correctly. When I hover over the tooltip, it shows a grey box with the tooltip text instead of the proper black box. What am I doing wrong here? [image]

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li> {{ link_to("/personas", '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-user', 'id' => 'personas', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'title' => 'View all personas')) }}</li>
        <li> {{ link_to("/tags", '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-tags', 'id' => 'tags', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'title' => 'View all tags')) }}</li>

      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
@('document').ready(function(){

  $('personas').tooltip();
  $('tags').tooltip();

});
</script>
```

Comment: It's `$('document')...`, there is no `@` var, it's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In your script section you are missing the **css ID selector**. Without this, jQuery does not know if it should serach for a class or an id. An id is shown with a **#** a class with a **.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){

  $('#personas').tooltip();
  $('#tags').tooltip();
```

});

Comment: this still did not fix the problem

Comment: Are there any JS erors in the console?

Comment: sry, my fault. There was a syntax error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In my `app.blade.php` file, there was the following line:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" defer></script>
```

By just removing the `defer`, my tooltip was styled properly.

```
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```